# Pythonify Some Simple Loops

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Currently, I am developing a huge test suite, where each file undergoes exactly 387,072 tests, and I have 269 files I need to test. I wrote all the logic in Python, and it all does what it is supposed to do, but the problem is it is terribly slow.

I think I have identified the major bottlenecks in the code. Basically, these bottlenecks seem to stem from me using Python to do C-style index for loops. I would be very grateful if someone could help me get better at Python by learning how to Pythonify the following:

```
for i in range(len(mixed)):
    if (len(signal1Data.shape)>1):
        for row in range(signal1Data.shape[0]):
            if (i>=signal1Data[row,0] and i<=signal1Data[row,1]):
                signal1Indicator[i] = 1;
    else:
        if (i>=signal1Data[0] and i<=signal1Data[1]):
            signal1Indicator[i] = 1;
```

And:

```
for i in range(1,len(changed),2):
    changed[i] -= 1;
```

Where signal1Data looks like:

```
0 5000
5100 6778
8000 9246
...
etc
```

Basically, I am trying to mix two signals, and then create an indicator when the index is between the values in signal1Data. How can I speed this up via a Pythonification?

Edit:

mixed holds the final signal that I am mixing. It looks like:

mixed = [-0.943263, -0.823721, -0.582382, -0.24921389, 0.000, ... etc]

Similarly, signal1 is just another signal, of the same format.

signal1Data defines where certain events are occurring. In my example, the event I am interested in happens between 0 and 5000, and then again between 5100 and 6778 etc. These numbers are the sample indices where the event is occurring in the signal. By the time this loop comes around, signal1Data is a 2D array of integers (but sometimes it can be 1D because there is only 1 event and I am loading it with numpy.loadtxt).

Comment: Does whatever pythonic code we provide still have to loop through all those elements?  If it does, I doubt that making it pythonic will improve its speed.

Comment: It would help if we knew better what some of the identifiers meant. What kind of data is in `mixed`? What is `signal1Data` exactly?

Comment: Why are you ending your statements with semicolons? That is unidiomatic and a little jarring. (Putting unnecessary parentheses around `if` conditions, too.)

Comment: It also would be helpful if you could show us some example values of `mixed` and `signal1Data` to test on

Comment: It doesn't have to loop through all those elements if it does the same thing. Basically, I want to check if the index corresponds to when some event is happening, and place an indicator flag. I only have bounds on when the event starts (the left column) and ends (the right column).

Comment: Is your data sorted in any way?

Comment: Basically, all I want to do is make signal1Indicator = 1 for all indices that fall between the left and right columns of signal1Data. The signals themselves are not sorted, but signal1Data is. As in if you flattened it, each value would be greater than the one before.

Comment: "387,072 tests, and I have 269 files I need to test." It seems like you are testing too much... I'm pretty sure you can reduce the 380k tests to about 1000 *without* loss of actual "test coverage".

Comment: That is not what I asked. Please leave relevant comments.

Comment: @TheDude That's why I posted that as a comment and not as an answer. Answers should be strictly related to the question, comments are there *in order* to provide/ask further information about the question and pointing out other problem with the question. In your case it's pretty clear that you have fallen in the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you search a bit on SO you'll notice that a lot of comments contain jokes, orthogonal information etc.

Comment: Ah, I apologize. Well its a performance test for something but yes, I understand what you mean. The issue is that there are 6 questions I need to answer, and they all require multiple dimensions. If I were to reduce the number of tests, I would have to increase the parameter step size, and hence rely more on interpolation. I could, potentially, for instance take steps of 10 instead of 5 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, you can remove the outer loop and the `if`'s by making use of slicing:

```
for start, stop in np.atleast_2d(signal1Data):
    signal1Indicator[start:stop+1] = 1
```

I'm not sure if you could vectorize this entirely.. if you could, it will probably be both faster as less clear and less Pythonic `:)`.

The second one is easy, also by slicing:

```
changed[1::2] -= 1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. It has sped things up considerably!! Btw: To me this is more Pythonic because it makes use of 1. slicing, and 2. a numpy built in. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only improvement I can think of at the moment is to change `if... else` to `try.. except`, like so:

```
for i in range(len(mixed)):
    try:
        for row in range(signal1Data.shape[0]):
            #Index Error exception is thrown below, if signal1Data is an array
            if (i>=signal1Data[row,0] and i<=signal1Data[row,1]):
                signal1Indicator[i] = 1
    except IndexError:
        if (i>=signal1Data[0] and i<=signal1Data[1]):
            signal1Indicator[i] = 1
```

Other small improvement that comes to my mind <strike>is changing the `for i in range(len(mixed))` - not sure what `mixed` is, but you're calculating two things here and both might be unnecessary.</strike> Not after your edit

Also you're calculating `range(signal1Data.shape[0])` every loop. I couldn't find anything about `shape` time complexity, but if `mixed` is big enough, creating `range(signal1Data.shape[0])` outside the for loop might help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think having a more idiomatic code will make it faster but here are a few things you can do:

for loops

```
for i in range(len(mixed)):
```

Has sense only if you want i to be a number, otherwise you can use

```
for item in some_list:
```

And item will take successively the values stored in some_list.

To check if a list empty you can do

```
if some_list:
```

an empty list will evaluate like false and a non empty list will evaluate like true. It is not necessary to check the length.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to do, but you can do something like this to create a mask based on the index of the array.

```
data = np.arange(20).reshape(2,10) 
i,j = np.meshgrid(*map(np.arange, data.shape), indexing='ij')
mask = (j > 2) & (j < 6)
#To get the values this mask defines, do this.
data[mask].reshape(data.shape[0],-1)
```